# How to make each column evenly spaced?

Tags: spacing, multicolumn

The last $x_3$ column has a larger space than other columns. How to solve? Thanks. I want all the $x_1$, $x_2$ and $x_3$ in the table to be evenly spaced.

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr|rrr}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}^{\prime} = [0, 0, 0]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}^{\prime} = [0, 0, -1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}^{\prime} = [1, 0, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}^{\prime} = [1, 1, 1] $} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}^{\prime} = [-1, -1, -1]$} \\
\hline
$x_1$ &  $x_2$ &  $x_3$ &  
$x_1$ &  $x_2$ &  $x_3$ & 
$x_1$ &  $x_2$ &  $x_3$ & 
$x_1$ &  $x_2$ &  $x_3$ & 
$x_1$ &  $x_2$ &  $x_3$ \\
\hline
$-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ &   1    & 0    & 1    &  1    & 0    & 1    &  1    & $-1$ & $-1$ &  $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ \\
$-1$ & 1    & 1    &   $-1$ & $-1$ & 1    &  0    & 1    & 0    &  1    & 0    & 0    &  $-1$ & $-1$ & $-1$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

you can use a  `wr` column so they are specifed width and wider than the spanning columns. If you squeeze the white space it (just) fits in `article` width (or you could use `\small`)

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{R}{>$wr{20.4pt}<$}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.3pt}
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}RRR|RRR|RRR|RRR|RRR@{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{@{}c|}{$\mathbf{r}' {=} [0, 0, 0]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' {=} [0, 0, -1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' {=} [1, 0, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' {=} [1, 1, 1] $} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathbf{r}' {=} [-1, -1, -1]\!$} \\
\hline
x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 &  
x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 & 
x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 & 
x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 & 
x_1 &  x_2 &  x_3 \\
\hline
-1 & -1 & -1 &   1    & 0    & 1    &  1    & 0    & 1    &  1    & -1 & -1 &  -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1    & 1    &   -1 & -1 & 1    &  0    & 1    & 0    &  1    & 0    & 0    &  -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

- Unfortunately used `\documentclass` nor document page layout are unknown.
- Table with 15 columns is quite wide, so it can't be fit in default defined article text block.
- Equal width of columns is simple to obtain by use of the `X` column type defined  in the `tabularx` or `tabularray` packages.
- In MWE below I define page layout is used default page layout provided by  `geometry` package and for table use `tblr` of `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{hlines, vlines,
             colspec = {*{15}{X[c, mode=math]} },
             cell{1}{1,4,7,10,13} = {c=3}{}
            }
\mathbf{r}' = [0, 0, 0]
    &   &   &   \mathbf{r}' = [0, 0, -1]
                &   &   &   \mathbf{r}' = [1, 0, 1]
                            &   &   &   \mathbf{r}' = [1, 1, 1]
                                        &   &   &    \mathbf{r}' = [-1, -1, -1] \\
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 
    & x_1 & x_2 & x_3
        & x_1 & x_2 & x_3
            & x_1 & x_2 & x_3
                & x_1 & x_2 & x_3   \\
-1 & -1 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  1 & 1  & -1 & -1 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The title of your query asks how to make all 15 columns of the `tabular` environment have the same width. Actually, I think that all that's really needed is to make the *final two columns* have the same width, so that they -- together with column 13 -- fill out the width of the associated header, which is `$\mathbf{r}'=[-1,-1,-1]$`.

The reason for why I think that modifying the properties of just two columns may be preferable is that the table is already quite wide, and might in fact be close to exceeding the width of the text block. Increasing the widths of all 15 columns, instead of just the final 2, will almost certainly make it a lot more difficult to fit the table properly.

The following code and associated screenshot show how calculating the required width may be accomplished with the help of the `w` column type, which is provided by the `array` package. The screenshot shows the table both without and then with the width adjustment. Observe that the first 13 columns have the same widths in both tables.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type and \newcolumntype macro
\usepackage{calc} % simplify calculation in TeX
\newcolumntype{R}{>{$}r<{$}} % automatic inline math mode
\newcolumntype{W}[1]{>{$}wr{#1}<{$}}
\newlength\mylen % for calculation of width of final 2 columns

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\setlength\tabcolsep{5.35pt} % default: 6pt
\setlength\extrarowheight{1.5pt} % for a less-cramped look

\begin{tabular}{@{} RRR|RRR|RRR|RRR|RRR @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [0, 0, 0]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [0, 0,-1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [1, 0, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [1, 1, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathbf{r}'=[-1,-1,-1]$} \\
\hline
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
\hline
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1 &  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  1 &  1 &-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip
% calculate the width of the final two columns
\settowidth\mylen{$\mathbf{r}'=[-1,-1,-1]$} 
\setlength\mylen{(\mylen-\widthof{$-1$}-4\tabcolsep)/2}

\begin{tabular}{@{} RRR|RRR|RRR|RRR|R *{2}{W{\mylen}} @{}}
\hline
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [0, 0, 0]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [0, 0,-1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [1, 0, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{$\mathbf{r}' = [1, 1, 1]$} &   
\multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{$\mathbf{r}'=[-1,-1,-1]$} \\
\hline
x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 \\
\hline
-1 & -1 & -1 & 1 &  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
-1 &  1 &  1 &-1 & -1 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 &  0 &  0 & -1 & -1 & -1 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```